# Bootstrap: fluid table too wide for window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table, fluid-layout

I'm working on a project using twitter bootstrap. We have a table that has lots of columns and is going to be larger than the browser window almost every time.

This is what happens on the right :

[image: The Problem]

The table border stays in the browser window, while the table contents do not. If I scroll, the borders stay where they are, they do not "follow" the browser window.

You can see the problem [on this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qN6L7/1/). It works on Safari, not on Chrome or Firefox.

The layout is like this :

```
<body>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row-fluid'>
      <div class='span1'>
        ... menusidebar here...
      </div>
      <div class='span11'>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="white-space: nowrap">
          <thead>
            <tr>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I hope you can help me. If you need more information, just ask, I'd be glad to supply.

This is a Rails 3.2 app, using the gem bootstrap-sass in version 2.2.1.1 (the problem appears in 2.2.2.0 too). The first three numbers reflect the bootstrap version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bootstrap has the following style applied to Tables:

```
table {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

If you override that property in your custom stylesheet it should hopefully solve the problem. Changing it to 'none' should work.

```
table {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: actually, I had to set it to 'none', I let you edit your answer. Thanks a lot : )

Comment: Hmm, strange as I had changed it to 'auto' via Firebug and that worked. Ah well, I'll change it to 'none' in my answer anyway.

Comment: Note: This is now outdated, there's far better methods with the release of bootstrap3 and the upcoming bootstrap4

Comment: TheGeorgeL what are some of these better methods?

Answer (score 33):

This was the only solution that worked for me...

```
    .table {
        max-width: none;
        table-layout: fixed;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! You are right. That was the only thing that worked for me as well (Bootstrap 3).

Comment: For me too (Bootstrap 5.1.3). Thank you.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 25):

If you are on Bootstrap 3, another approach is to wrap your table in a

```
<div class="table-responsive"><table>...</table></div>
```

This makes the table responsive.

Comment: thanks, this helped me resolve my similar issue, upvote

Comment: definitely the best answer here

Comment: This should be marked as the best answer, clean and uses what already exists in bootstrap

Answer (score 4):

You can apply the style = "overflow: auto;" to put a horizontal scroll bar at your table. Thus the design will still remain responsive. Follow the code:

```
.table-scrollable{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

And use it on your div:

```
<div class='span11 table-scrollable'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying the style = "overflow: auto;" worked just fine for me

Answer (score -1):

I found solution somewhere in internet...

```
table {table-layout:fixed}
```

It solve problems in Firefox & IE, with bootstrap 2 & 3